# Javascript, MongoDB context -- TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'collection')

Tags: javascript, mongodb, typeerror, uri, mongodb-compass

I recently came across the error popping up in terminal or command prompt mentioned in the question above.

Exact error shown is:

```
const taskCollection = db.collection('tasks');
                              ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'collection')
    at Command.<anonymous> (C:\Abc\xyz\Task-Manager-CLI-Project\index.js:50:31)
    at Command.listener [as _actionHandler] (C:\Abc\xyz\Task-Manager-CLI-Project\node_modules\commander\lib\command.js:494:17)
    at C:\Abc\xyz\Task-Manager-CLI-Project\node_modules\commander\lib\command.js:1296:65
    at Command._chainOrCall (C:\Abc\xyz\Task-Manager-CLI-Project\node_modules\commander\lib\command.js:1193:12)
    at Command._parseCommand (C:\Abc\xyz\Task-Manager-CLI-Project\node_modules\commander\lib\command.js:1296:27)
    at C:\Abc\xyz\Task-Manager-CLI-Project\node_modules\commander\lib\command.js:1082:27
    at Command._chainOrCall (C:\Abc\xyz\Task-Manager-CLI-Project\node_modules\commander\lib\command.js:1193:12)
    at Command._dispatchSubcommand (C:\Abc\xyz\Task-Manager-CLI-Project\node_modules\commander\lib\command.js:1078:25)
    at Command._parseCommand (C:\Abc\xyz\Task-Manager-CLI-Project\node_modules\commander\lib\command.js:1264:19)
    at Command.parse (C:\Abc\xyz\Task-Manager-CLI-Project\node_modules\commander\lib\command.js:910:10)
```

**This is a simple task manager CLI project. I have connected mongoDB with my project, still it shows the same error and I am not getting where the error is? How do I solve it**
Here are my 2 code files:

**db.js**

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
const uri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';

//we have used MongoDB Node.js driver to connect js to MongoDB database.

const client = new MongoClient(uri)

let db;

async function connect(){
    try{
        await client.connect();
        db = client.db('task_manager_db'); 
        
        // it is selecting the database named 'taskmanager'. If the specified database does not exist, MongoDB will create it when you first write data to it.
        //now variable db holds the reference to 'taskmanager' database
        
        console.log('Connected to the database');
    } catch(err){
        console.log('Error connecting to the database...', err);
    }
}

function getDB(){
    return db;
}

module.exports = {connect, getDB};
```

**index.js**

```
//using commander.js library for the project
//commander.js library provides functions that can run the project on CLI mode.
//Which is the ultimate aim and learning behind the project: To create and run a project using CLI.

const program = require('commander');

//importing the functions from db.js
const {connect, getDB} = require('./db');

program
.version('1.0.0')
.description('Task Manager CLI')
//connecting MongoDB database (i.e. to the uri to be specific)
.action(connect());

//general structure of defining commands for CLI using commander.js library
// program
// .command('')
// .description('')
// .action(//function inside() => { });

//command to list all tasks --> list
program
.command('list')
.description('list of commands')
.action(async() => {
    //extract database from function
    const db = getDB();
    //refer to the collection in db
    const taskCollection = db.collection('tasks');

    try{
        const tasks = await taskCollection.find().toArray();
        console.log("Listing all the tasks:");
        tasks.forEach((task_) => {
            console.log(`- ${tasks.task_}`);
        });
    }catch(err){
        console.log("Error displaying tasks...");
    }

});

//command to add a task --> add <taskname>
program
.command('add <taskname>')
.description('Add a new task')
.action(async() => {
    const db = getDB();
    const taskCollection = db.collection('tasks');

    try{
        const result = await taskCollection.insertOne({ taskname });
        console.log(`New Task added: ${task} TaskID: ${result.insertedId}`);
    }catch(err){
        console.log("Error adding task...", err);
    }
});

//command to delete task --> delete <TaskId>
program
.command("delete <TaskId>")
.description("Delete a task")
.action(async() => {
    const db = getDB();
    const taskCollection = await db.collection('tasks');

    try{
        const result = await tasksCollection.deleteOne({ _id: new ObjectId(TaskId) });
        console.log(`Deleted Task (ID: ${TaskId}`);
    }catch(err){
        console.log("Error deleting a task...", err);
    }
});

program.parse(process.argv);
```

1. I tried changing the URI from my MongoDB compass, even renamed it from **"New Connection"** TO **"Project1"** then copied the URI to **db.js** file. Didn't work.
2. I tried changing the URI from **mongodb://localhost:27017** to **mongodb://localhost:27018**
   **OR** from **mongodb://localhost:27017** to **mongodb://localhost:27017/Project1** still didn't work. The error still pops.

Expected output is the commands **list, add , delete** should run on command prompt and show the coded console.log() outputs or error handling outputs. Instead it says the collection **tasks** of my database **task_manager_db** is undefined and hence cannot read its properties.

Comment: Do you see either of the messages printed by your `connect` function?

Comment: You get the error because `db` is undefined. It is undefined because you call `getDB` synchronously after having called `connect`: this cannot work because the part in `connect` that follows after `await` has not executed yet. You should not call `getDB` before the promise returned by `connect` has resolved.

Comment: No @smallpepperz, there weren't any messages printed by connect function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `connect()` is an asynchronous function, you should return `db` within that function itself and use `await` in your `index.js` file like this:

**db.js**

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
const uri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';
const client = new MongoClient(uri)

let db;

async function connect(){
    try{
        await client.connect();
        db = client.db('task_manager_db'); 
        return db;
    } catch(err){
        console.log('Error connecting to the database...', err);
    }
}

module.exports = {connect};
```

**index.js**

```
const program = require('commander');
const {connect} = require('./db');

program
.version('1.0.0')
.description('Task Manager CLI');

program
.command('list')
.description('list of commands')
.action(async() => {
    const db = await connect();
    const taskCollection = db.collection('tasks');

    try{
        const tasks = await taskCollection.find().toArray();
        console.log("Listing all the tasks:");
        tasks.forEach((task_) => {
            console.log(`- ${tasks.task_}`);
        });
    }catch(err){
        console.log("Error displaying tasks...");
    }

});

program
.command('add <taskname>')
.description('Add a new task')
.action(async() => {
    const db = await connect();
    const taskCollection = db.collection('tasks');

    try{
        const result = await taskCollection.insertOne({ taskname });
        console.log(`New Task added: ${task} TaskID: ${result.insertedId}`);
    }catch(err){
        console.log("Error adding task...", err);
    }
});

program
.command("delete <TaskId>")
.description("Delete a task")
.action(async() => {
    const db = await connect();
    const taskCollection = await db.collection('tasks');

    try{
        const result = await tasksCollection.deleteOne({ _id: new ObjectId(TaskId) });
        console.log(`Deleted Task (ID: ${TaskId}`);
    }catch(err){
        console.log("Error deleting a task...", err);
    }
});

program.parse(process.argv);
```

Comment: can't I just simply connect MongoDb database just once for throughout the index.js file at the very top of the code, instead of connecting in every "commander program"?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your connection to MongoDB. The connection to MongoDB is async. Wait for the connection to complete using the **async** function on your **commander action**. In your case, the index.js, the snipet to connect to mongo should look like this:

```
program
.version('1.0.0')
.description('Task Manager CLI')
//connecting MongoDB database 
.action(async ()=>{
   await connect());
}
```

This should ensure your connection is complete before you can run any commands.

[async actions in commander.js](https://github.com/tj/commander.js/issues/505)

[MongoDB reason behind Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'collection')](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/solved-mern-tutorial-issue-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-collection/212521)

Comment: But `connect()` itself is defined as an async function in `db.js` file, so why do I have to again write it `async()=> {
await connect()});` ?